# Laravel - Использование связи многие к одному

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть таблицы: Тур и Страна. У таблицы Тур заранее предопределено, что только одна страна может соответствовать туру. Но, возможны ситуации, что несколько туров возможны в одной стране и появляется связь многие к одному.

Реализация вывода всех элементов:

```
@foreach($tours as $tour)
  <form action="/">
    <table class="tours">
        <tr>
            <td>Название: {{ $tour->name }}</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Заказать" name="buy" class="button special"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Дата начала тура: {{ $tour->date_start }}</td>
            <td>Дата завершения тура: {{ $tour->date_end }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Количество человек: {{ $tour->people }}</td>
            <td>Питание: <?php echo \App\Http\Controllers\MainController::getEat($tour->eat); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Страна: {{ $tour->country->name }}</td>
        ..
@endforeach
```

Мои миграции:

```
Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name',40);
    $table->date('date_start');
    $table->date('date_end');
    $table->integer('idCountry')->references('id')->on('countries');
...
}
//Внешний ключ
    Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('idCountry')->references('id')->on('countries');
    }
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name',50);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Метод country для получения из модели:

```
public function country(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Countries', 'id');
}
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что если создать одну страну и два тура, то при выводе всех элементов - падает ошибка на 2ом туре (у его тура id = 1 и он есть в БД, и его выводит) по причине того, что он пытается выбрать страну с id = 2 , хотя в БД id = 1.

Есть подозрения, что проблема в методе country().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В определении `hasOne` второй параметр это поле с ИД страны. Оно у вас определяется как

```
$table->integer('idCountry')
```

Следовательно:

```
public function country(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Countries', 'idCountry');
}
```

Comment: Другая ошибка тогда появляется

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.idCountry' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where `countries`.`idCountry` = 1 and `countries`.`idCountry` is not null limit 1) (View: /home/vagrant/code/dev/resources/views/main.blade.php)

Comment: Окей, тогда попробуйте `$this->hasOne('App\Countries', 'id', 'idCountry');`

Comment: Ура, заработало! Спасибо! :)